# Proving inverse implication by conversion

Tags: proof-verification

I have proven logically that the inverse of an implication is true if and only if the converse of said implication is true (as shown below).

proposition 1: k has same parity as 2j

proposition 2: k is even

implication: If k is even, then k has the same parity as 2j.

inverse: If k does not have the same parity as 2j, then k is not even.

converse: If k is not even, then k does not have the same parity as 2j.

My question is, how can I write this in a mathematical notation? I know that I can write the propositions' mathematical notations as such:

k => 2j

But how should I write my implication? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The converse of the **implication** should be 

"If  $k$ is even, then $k$ has the same parity as $2j$."

What you stated is the **contrapositive**.

Comment: @MarkLao thanks, but isn't your correction just dealing with semantics? Couldn't it just swap proposition 1 and 2 to correct my implication?

Comment: If you swap propositions 1 and 2, what you stated as converse becomes the **inverse**.

Comment: Just to be clear, the converse you stated is **not** the converse of the implication. But it is the **converse of the inverse** of the implication that you stated.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the mistake. Could you please provide any thought on the mathematical notation of the proposition? Thanks again.

Comment: I actually don't understand what you want to do. By "write in a mathematical notation", do you mean to write mainly using math symbols instead of words?

Comment: @marklao Yes, how can I write the above if then else statement mathematically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20521/discussion-between-jim22150-and-mark-lao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming to "write this in a mathematical notation" means to write mainly using math symbols instead of words, then you may say:

> Let $E$ be the set of even integers.
>
> If $k \in E$, then $k \equiv 2j\pmod2.$

Or the more extreme version:

> $k \in E \Rightarrow k \equiv 2j\pmod2$.

But the way you stated the implication is perfectly fine, if not better.